# How can I stop the stream when I pause the download file in browser because of it leads memory leak

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, download, out-of-memory

As title say,I am downloading a file ,it's well done unless I pause the download progress.I am using the following backend codes to download my files,which can install >10Gb file(mostly important).

```
    public void TransmitFileAsync()
    {
        System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

        string fullPath = "D:\\backend-fileupload\\test.rar";

        string outFileName = "test.rar";

        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[10485760];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;

        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        // Identify the file to download including its path.
        string filepath = fullPath;

        // Identify the file name.
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open,
                        FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);


            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;

            Response.Clear();

            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + outFileName );

            /*Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");*/

            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", iStream.Length.ToString());

            Response.Headers.AcceptRanges = "bytes";

            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {

                CancellationToken cancellationToken = HttpContext.RequestAborted;
               /* bool isPause = HttpContext.*/


                // Verify that the client is connected.
                // Read db auth ? or set in xml file and read
                if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && true)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10485760);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    Response.Body.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the output.
                    Response.Body.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[10485760];

                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            Response.Body.Close();
            
        }
    }
```

and front-end:

```
fetch(requesturl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream",
                 
            },

        }).then(res  => {

            const readableStream = res.body;
            
            const name = "test.rar"

            const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream(name, {
                size: Number(res.headers.get("Content-Length"))
            })
            
            if (window.WritableStream && readableStream?.pipeTo) {
                console.log('111done writing...')
                return readableStream.pipeTo(fileStream).then(() => {
                    console.log('done writing...')
                })
            }
            const reader = readableStream?.getReader();
            const writer = fileStream.getWriter();
            window.onunload = () => {
                fileStream.abort()
                // also possible to call abort on the writer you got from `getWriter()`
                writer.abort()
            }
            
            const pump: any = () =>
                reader?.read()
                    .then(res => res.done ? writer.close() : writer.write(res.value));
            pump();
```

and the problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUYcn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV5Nn.png)

I just know that when I pause the downloading file,the backend codes is still in the loop of while(),how can I stop or pause it to solve this problem?

Comment: it is a bug ,look at this link : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642673，anyone knows how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CacheControl and set it "no-store",and then the stream can not pull in the cache

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).